# using sed to extract a time from a line

Tags: regex, sed

line:

```
0.01user 0.00system 0:13.46elapsed 0%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 4272maxresident)k
```

I want to grab:

```
0:13.46
```

my current regex is:

```
sed 's/.*\([0-9]*:[0-9]*.[0-9]*\)elapsed.*/\1/'
```

I'm pretty sure the regex is correct, but it's not finding anything. It's probably something really simple, I'm just doing 10 things at once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me:

```
% sed 's/.*\s\([0-9]*:[0-9]*.[0-9]*\)elapsed.*/\1/'
0.01user 0.00system 0:13.46elapsed 0%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 4272maxresident)k
0:13.46
```

Note how I put a `\s` before the first digit you want to match.

Then again, your regex kind of worked for me before in that it would print out `:13.46` (the `.*` gobbled up the first `0` that you want to print out).

Answer (score 0):

Why not use awk?

```
awk '/elapsed/ {gsub(/elapsed/,""); print $3}'
```

I tried your sed expression on SL and got `:13.46`

Answer (score 0):

I got `:13.46`. This is caused by the initial `.*` which expands as much as possible without compromising the following `[0-9]*:`.

My suggestion: `sed 's/.*system //;s/elapsed.*//'`

Answer (score 0):

If you have a version of `time` that supports the format option, you don't need to parse its output:

```
$ /usr/bin/time -f %E sleep 2.27
0:02.27
```

In Bash, using its builtin `time`:

```
$ TIMEFORMAT=%R
$ time sleep 2.27
2.337
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another solution:

`echo $word | grep -oP '[^ ]*(?=elapsed)'`

This looks for the largest character string before 'elapsed' which does not contain a space character.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a problem for which awk is better suited. You can solve this in awk without using regular expressions which are (relatively) inefficient.

```
awk '{ print substr($3, 1, length($3) - 7) }'
```

In a test I just ran, this awk solution is an order of magnitude faster than the accepted sed solution. I believe the significant performance improvement comes from avoiding regular expressions.